# Uber authorization url

Tags: oauth

I am trying to generate authorize url for uber

https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&response_type=code&scope=history&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback

OK

https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&response_type=code&scope=history&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback

LOGIN.ERROR.INVALID_SCOPE

https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&response_type=code&scope=profile%2Chistory&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback

LOGIN.ERROR.INVALID_SCOPE

Anyone facing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try using the IP address instead of the localhost;
2. Make sure the redirect url string matches the one on your app dashboard;
3. Make sure you have ticked all of the scopes.